# Firebase functions search query realtime database with nodejs

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my database

```
"Users" : {
        "2rnWA7TF11gSWxec7MsCA5iRhjw1" : {
          "favoriteCount" : 1,
          "interest" : [ "dogs", "cats", "technology" ],
          "speciality" : [ "Swift" ],
        },
        "3Id9oX0ZOEM00XJlnR07gGrHs762" : {
          "favoriteCount" : 7,
          "interest" : [ "dogs", "cats", "Asp.NET MVC", "JavaScript" ],
          "speciality" : [ "Microsoft Technologys" ],

      }
```

I want to access user information interest=dogs in whole database how can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Your current data structure allows you to easily look up the interests for a specific user. It does not however allow easy lookup for the users for a specific interest.

To allow looking up the users for an interest, you'll want to add an inverted data structure `/Interests/$interest` with the user ID for each user under there:

```
"Interests": {
  "dogs": {
    "2rnWA7TF11gSWxec7MsCA5iRhjw1": true,
    "3Id9oX0ZOEM00XJlnR07gGrHs762": true
  },
  "cats": {
    "2rnWA7TF11gSWxec7MsCA5iRhjw1": true,
    "3Id9oX0ZOEM00XJlnR07gGrHs762": true
  },
  "technology": {
    "2rnWA7TF11gSWxec7MsCA5iRhjw1": true,
  }
  ...
}
```

Also see:

- my longer [answer on querying items in categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)
- [Firebase's vintage blog post explaining why you shouldn't use an array](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html)

Comment: it does not seem possible because I do not have a specific area

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Can you rephrase that?

Comment: I don't have a specific dog and cat area,each user can create a desired field

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I like the "**vintage** blog post"!! :-)))

Comment: @AhmetSaz: This is the idiomatic way to solve categorization-queries in Firebase's realtime database. The keys in my additional data structure can also be create ad-hoc as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can make queries in Firebase:

```
Query query = usersDB.orderByChild("interest").equalTo("WHATEVERINTEREST");

query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
     Users user = dataSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
     doWhatever();
   }
});
```

However in your case as you store the information as an Array, what you can do is retrieve all the users and in your code get the information you need.

```
 usersDB.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                ArrayList<Users> listOfUsers = new ArrayList<Users>();

                for (DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    Users user = dsp.getValue(Users.class);
                    listOfUsers.add(user);
                }

                //Check the Users that contains interest
                usersWithInterest(listOfUsers,"dogs");

            }


        });
```

Implement an easy method that read all the list of users and check the users with a interest in dogs:

```
 usersWithInterest(listOfUsers, "dogs");
```

Comment: How can I with nodejs I dont know java :)

Comment: The concept is the same, just make it in nodeJS. Nevertheless I would strongly recommend use the approach @FrankvanPuffelen used in his answer. Is more efficient.